# Add a legend to a chart that uses alt.condition to filter values

Tags: python, visualization, altair

[image: Image I am trying to replicate]

Hi, I am trying to replicate the plot on the image above, but I just can figure out the legend part. Here is a sample of a toy dataframe:

```py
toy = pd.DataFrame(
                {'Bushes':[0,0,1,1,0], 'Trees': [1,1,0,0,0],
                 'Lake':[0,0,0,0,1], 'x': [1,3,-1,4,2],
                 'y': [2,0,-2,1,3]}
                    )
```

The x and y are values for placing the rectangles.
The other columns ['Bushes','Trees,'Lake'] are features that are shown in some drawings.

The visualization chart should highlight the rectangles (images in the image snippet but just using the rectangles for simplicity) that contain the features.

This is my working code:

```py
    key = 'Snow'

    rect = alt.Chart(br).mark_rect( height = 25, width = 25
                         ).encode(
                                    alt.X('x', axis = None),
                                    alt.Y('y', axis = None),
                                    color = alt.condition(
                                                          alt.datum[key] == 1,
                                                          alt.value('red'),
                                                          alt.value('lightgray'))                                    
                                            )
```

but this code does not show the legend. I need help!

from my past experience seems that some how I need to define color to be a "Nominal" type and then use it along with alt.Scale.

I tried :

```py
   rect = alt.Chart(br).mark_rect( height = 25, width = 25
                         ).encode(
                                    alt.X('x', axis = None),
                                    alt.Y('y', axis = None),
                                    color = alt.Color(alt.condition(
                                                          alt.datum[key] == 1,
                                                          alt.value('red'),
                                                          alt.value('lightgray')), 'type:Nominal'                                    
                                            ))
```

without success, then it occur to me to use the transform_calculate method to define a new variable on the main dataframe:

```py
#     rect = alt.Chart(br).mark_rect(height=25, width=25).encode(
#         alt.X('x', axis=None),
#         alt.Y('y', axis=None),
#         color=alt.Color('condition:N',  
#         scale=alt.Scale(domain=[f"Has a(n) '{key}'", f"Does not have a(n) '{key}'"], range=['red', 'lightgray']))
#                         ).transform_calculate(
#                                             condition=alt.condition(
#                                                             alt.datum[key] == 1, True, False)
```

so I intended calculate the 'condition' variable and define it on the color encoding channel, the transform_calculate should be replicating my original code and filtering based on the presence of the feature , but I keep getting an error message.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the conditional statment, you can set the range in the color scale instead:

```
toy = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Bushes':[0,0,1,1,0], 'Trees': [1,1,0,0,0],
     'Lake':[0,0,0,0,1], 'x': [1,3,-1,4,2],
     'y': [2,0,-2,1,3]}
)

alt.Chart(toy).mark_rect(height = 25, width = 25).encode(
    alt.X('x', axis = None),
    alt.Y('y', axis = None),
    alt.Color('Trees:N', scale=alt.Scale(range=['lightgray', 'red']))
)
```

[image]